# How to adjust client side timeout in a C# windows form application app.config file, calling web service as a web reference

Tags: c#, winforms, web-services, timeout, app-config

In a windows form application, if i call web service as a service reference i easily adjust client side time out in app.config bindings like this:

when i call svc it automatically gives me bindings, i only add timeouts:

```
 <binding openTimeout = "00:00:05"
         closeTimeout = "00:00:05"
         sendTimeout = "00:00:05"
         receiveTimeout = "00:00:05"  name="CustomBinding_srvEx">
```

But if i call web service as a web reference i cant adjust client side timeout.
Where should i write the timeout settings in app.config. No binding it gives in app.config.

when i call asmx it gives me those codes in app.config:

```
<applicationSettings>
        <timeout.Properties.Settings>
            <setting  name="timeout_deneme" serializeAs="String">
                <value>https:....asmx</value>
            </setting>
        </timeout.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the timeout via code and read the value from your app.config

```
var client = new MyService();
client.InnerChannel.OperationTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0); // read value from app.config
```

Comment: i dont understand anything. my codes does not accept those.

Comment: MyService doesnt contain a definition for innerChannel

Comment: what type of service are you referencing?

Comment: soap   
srvFabGis srv = new srvFabGis();
srv.Timeout = 10000; //10 second

The code above works but if I set the time out greater than 1 minute it doesn't work anymore

srvFabGis srv = new srvFabGis();
srv.Timeout = 600000; // 10 minutes

does not work